# Selecting random item from list having probability weighting using c#?

Tags: c#, logic

I have a scenario where i a was taking a list of users (20 users) from my database, where i was giving 
weighting for users

first 5 users probability factor of 4
next 5 users probability factor of 3
next 5 users probability factor of 2
next 5 users probability factor of 1

So an user that occurs in the first 5 users is 4 times more
likely to occur than an user in the last 5.

So how can i select a random user from the list using probability in c#?
can anybody help me in doing this i am totally stuck up logically?

Comment: I'm no probability expert, but couldn't you simply create a new list of 50 elements and insert each user in the list `x` times (where `x` is their weighting) and then pick one at random?  (5*4 + 5*3 + 5*2 + 5 = 50).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the uses the number of probability times in the list. So the 5 first users are 4 times in the list, next 5 users 3 times and so on. Then just select one user from the complete list.

Comment: This answer is useful but i have implemented this successfully using another way using WeightedRandom https://bitbucket.org/jonsagara/weightedrandom/wiki/Home

Comment: Actually, it is same way as described above by @GuydN. The only different is there is already a library for you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of partial sums of weights. In your example, it would be

```
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 23, ...]
```

The last element is the sum of all weights. Pick a random number between 0 and this sum (exclusive). Then your element is the first element with partial sum greater then the random number. So if you got 11, you need the third element, if you got 16, the fifth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a (bit hacky) solution for you:

Create a list containing the users, where each user is added as often as his weightage is. (e.g. User has a weightage of 5, add him 5 times to the list). Then us a `Random` to fetch a user from that list, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to find the smallest common denominator of the weights (or just multiply them together) and create a new list that contains the keys of the first list, but multiple times, ie:

user1
user1
user2
user3
user3
user3

Then just to a `newList.skip(Random.Next(newList.Count)).Take(1)` and you are set!

Answer (score 1):

You could apportion the probability range amongst the users using a dictionary. eg

User 1 has 1-4 (so max of 4)

User 2 has 5-8 (max of 8) etc etc...

Then after selecting the random number find which user within the dictionary it relates to. You can do this using Linq like so...

```
int iUser = users.Where(p => (choice <= p.Value)).First().Key;
```

..where `users` is a `Dictionary<int,int>` (Key = user number, Value = max value) and `choice` is the randomly generated value.

This is obviously more complex than the "multiple entries" method proposed by others but has its advantages if you

**a)** need a fractional weighting which makes the common denominator of your multiple entry method very small (resulting in many entries) *or*

**b)** need to weight heavily in favour of particular users (which would again have the effect of making the multiple entry method very large).

[Working Example at ideone.](http://ideone.com/NhmqC)